# How to insert foreign key in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, foreign-keys

I am developing an online event management web app for my college project. When a event organizer registers in app their values are stored in MySQL database with o_id as primary key which is auto incremented. But my problem is when the organizer logs in and want to advertise their event he has to fill up a event registration form. now the corresponding table to the event registration form has a foreign key with reference to the primary key o_id of the previous table. Now how to update the value of foreign key so that it can be known which organizer creates which event? Or any other way to connect these two tables?

Comment: create another table which holds the relevant fields.

Comment: Can you explain in more details please

Comment: My bad i misread your question. Before clicking on the page to show the events your servlet should check and see which event belongs to which user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, your problem is that your system don't know `organizer_id` when user is filling event registration form.

I suppose you already have two talbes, `organizers` and `events` where `events` have `organizer_id` foreign key on `organizers` primary key.

Now, what you need to do, is to store `organizer_id` in [HttpSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)(there a lot of tutorials on the Internet about session management) and also have hidden field in your registration form like this:

```
<form action="/">
  Event name: <input type="text" name="eventName"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="organizerId" value=${sessionScope.organizerId}>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Whenever the the organiser logs in he has to enter username and password only. So how can i store organiser_id in the session?  Or do i have to make organiser_id primary key?

Comment: Find organizer with this username and password in your db -> get his id -> store in the session.

Comment: Thanks so much for solving my issue. 

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark.